# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'protobuf.meta'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, protocol-buffers, android-espresso

I'm seeing some issues with compatibility between `com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0` and `com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1`
when used as dependencies on an android library module

I'm getting this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':mylibrary:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebugAndroidTest'.   
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'protobuf.meta'
```

when I try to execute `./gradlew :myLibrary:connectedAndroidTest`

Here's a barebones build.gradle that I've reproduced the problem on:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26



    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

I don't think I can exclude either of these files as the contents is different.

Comment: add `packagingOptions { exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES' }`

Comment: Gave me the same result

Comment: same problem for `11.4.2`?

Comment: 11.4.2, 11.4.0, and 11.2.0 all fail. 11.0.0 surprisingly works...

Comment: raise a bug there.

Comment: Raised here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69333598

Answer (score 16):

This issue occurred because you use two separate imports containing the same file. Your issue is with an external library that may have duplicate contents or was imported twice, to solve this You should put these lines of code inside *build.gradle* (Module: *app*).

Add the following lines:

```
android {
    // [...]
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'protobuf.meta'
    }
}
```

Sometimes, it is also possible to completely exclude this file: `exclude 'protobuf.meta'`

In case of multi-module projects, Android libraries failing to build due to this error on instrumentation tests, might need to include this snippet inside *build.gradle*.

Comment: Where? Why? Please provide more info.

Comment: This issue occurred because you use two separate imports containing the same file. Your issue is with an external library that may have duplicate contents or was imported twice, to solve this You should put these lines of code inside build.gradle(Module: app) .

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I can confirm that this works. Please update the answer and I’ll up vote it.

Comment: Thanks you so  much, i was stuck for long time, it worked.