# recent firebase, play services libs break build: More than one file was found with OS independent path 'google/protobuf/api.proto'

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

Started getting these errors:

```
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'google/protobuf/api.proto'
```

Also, for other proto files, like:

```
google/protobuf/type.proto
google/protobuf/timestamp.proto
google/protobuf/duration.proto
google/protobuf/empty.proto
...
```

I "fixed" it by making gradle pick first encountered, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47298895/more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-protobuf-meta/48006558), but not sure of the consequences during runtime.

**Upd**.: It followed with the following error:

```
Program type already present: com.google.protobuf.Any$Builder
```

**Upd 2** ./gradlew app:denepdencies:

```
devDebugCompileClasspath - Resolved configuration for compilation for variant: devDebug
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2 -> 1.0.3
+--- com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2 -> 27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    |    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0
|    |    |         +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1
|    |    |         +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |         +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0
|    |         |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0 (*)
|    |         |    +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0 (*)
|    |         |    \--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0
|    |         |         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1
|    |         |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0 (*)
|    |         \--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.2 -> 27.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2 -> 27.1.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:transition:27.1.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:preference-v7:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.1.0
+--- com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.2
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:[15.0.2] -> 15.0.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[15.0.2] -> 15.0.2
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[15.0.2] -> 15.0.2
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:15.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-audience:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1
|    +--- com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[15.0.2,16.0.0) -> 15.0.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[15.0.2] -> 15.0.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[15.0.2] -> 15.0.2
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[15.0.2] -> 15.0.2
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[15.1.0,16.0.0) -> 15.1.0
|    |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0
|    |    |              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[15.0.2] -> 15.0.2
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[15.0.2] -> 15.0.2 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[15.0.2] -> 15.0.2 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0
|              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-interop:[15.0.2,16.0.0) -> 15.0.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.2 (*)
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0
|    +--- io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.8.0
|    |    +--- io.grpc:grpc-core:[1.8.0] -> 1.8.0
|    |    |    +--- io.grpc:grpc-context:1.8.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 20.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.0.19
|    |    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.instrumentation:instrumentation-api:0.4.3
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 20.0
|    |    |    +--- io.opencensus:opencensus-api:0.8.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.0.19
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 20.0
|    |    |    \--- io.opencensus:opencensus-contrib-grpc-metrics:0.8.0
|    |    |         +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.0.19
|    |    |         \--- io.opencensus:opencensus-api:0.8.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0 -> 2.7.2 (*)
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.8.0
|    |    \--- io.grpc:grpc-core:1.8.0 (*)
|    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0
|    |    \--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    \--- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.8.0
|         +--- io.grpc:grpc-core:1.8.0 (*)
|         +--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1
|         \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 20.0
+--- com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.1
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0 -> 15.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0 -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:design:27.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta6 -> 1.1.0 (*)
|    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0
|    |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.0
|    |    |    +--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9
+--- org.joda:joda-convert:1.8.2
+--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13
+--- com.github.h6ah4i:android-advancedrecyclerview:0.11.0
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0
+--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0
+--- joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
+--- com.squareup:android-times-square:1.7.3
+--- com.squareup:otto:1.3.8
+--- com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0 -> 27.1.1
+--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6
+--- com.evernote:android-job:1.2.2
|    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.2 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3
+--- org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.4
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.0 -> 1.2.41
|         \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
+--- org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design:0.10.4
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.0 -> 1.2.41 (*)
|    \--- org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.4 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk25:0.10.4
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.0 -> 1.2.41 (*)
|    \--- org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.4 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:0.10.4
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.0 -> 1.2.41 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.anko:anko-support-v4:0.10.4
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.0 -> 1.2.41 (*)
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.4 (*)
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.anko:anko-support-v4-commons:0.10.4
|    |         +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.0 -> 1.2.41 (*)
|    |         \--- org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.4 (*)
|    \--- org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7-commons:0.10.4
|         +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.0 -> 1.2.41 (*)
|         \--- org.jetbrains.anko:anko-support-v4-commons:0.10.4 (*)
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.41 (*)
```

Latest error is:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDevDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.D8MainDexListTransform.transform(D8MainDexListTransform.kt:127)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList$MainDexListException: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: com.google.protobuf.Any$1
    at com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList.generate(D8MainDexList.java:87)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.D8MainDexListTransform.transform(D8MainDexListTransform.kt:114)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: com.google.protobuf.Any$1
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.resolveClassConflictImpl(ProgramClassCollection.java:64)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.lambda$create$0(ProgramClassCollection.java:25)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.merge(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1990)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.create(ProgramClassCollection.java:24)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.LazyLoadedDexApplication$Builder.build(LazyLoadedDexApplication.java:121)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:122)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:86)
    at com.android.tools.r8.GenerateMainDexList.run(GenerateMainDexList.java:40)
    at com.android.tools.r8.GenerateMainDexList.run(GenerateMainDexList.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList.generate(D8MainDexList.java:83)
    ... 53 more
```

Any ideas on how to better fix this?

Comment: Would you be able to include your dependency tree?  ./gradle :app:dependencies

Comment: @PaulR will add later today - don't have access now

Comment: @PaulR updated with stack and dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the protobuf library - not sure why I had included it in the first place years ago. It conflicted with the protobuf-lite that came as dependency by firebase.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem after I am using latest versions of firebase libraries. Following is the error I face. Can you please help me in solving this: Program type already present: com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos$DescriptorProtoOrBuilder

Comment: You need to build a dependency tree as described above and see where you have duplicated protobuf library

Comment: Found out, it was the googlephonelibrary. I was using an old version. Updating that fixed the issue.

Comment: For the time being, Firebase Firestore is not considered compatible with the public protobuf libraries. Proceed with caution.